# react-native version of HTML script tag?

Tags: react-native

I need to use the methods of an eternal API in my native project.

If this were react I would just do

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>`

for example, I don't need bootstrap specifically.

Is there a way to do this in react-native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) to manage your dependencies. Your react-native project should already be configured for this. You can install dependencies like this `npm install --save my-react-native-module`. Sometimes you will have to link them like this `react-native link my-react-native-module`. Most of those dependencies will write on their read me page how to install them.

Comment: Or better yet, `yarn`.